# How to find records searched in all columns of table with multiple keyword in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to search the data in all fields by any keywords which is separated by space

**For Example**

**Table Name:**`SampleTable`

```
col1    |  col2  |   col3    |   col4 |  col5
-----------------------------------------------
my      |  name  |    is     | john   | Abraham
Abraham |   is   |   good    | person | null
Name    |  will  | Describe  |  a     | person
```

If user search by word '**is**' 
`select * from SampleTable where allColumn=is`
It has to bring the result first two rows

```
my      |  name  |    is     | john   | Abraham
Abraham |   is   |   good    | person | null
```

if search by `is name`. It has to bring first row

```
my      |  name  |    is     | john   | Abraham
```

if search by `Abraham is`. It has to bring first and secend row

```
my      |  name  |    is     | john   | Abraham
Abraham |   is   |   good    | person | null
```

It's almost like search engine. Do you have any idea?.

Comment: so search is case sensitive right? since searching "name" excluded "Name"

Comment: @mastarhian no case sensitive.

Comment: pardon me.. was "is name"

Comment: @mastarhian "is" & "name" are 2 words, both words are presented in only one row. So i need that one row

Comment: This is a very strange requirement to say the least. You will need to use a string splitter to get the user input separated into words, then join to your table on any of those columns matching and get a count of the number of words sent in and the number of times a specific row matches. And what about if somebody searches for "name name"??

Comment: @SeanLange this is like full text search

Comment: well... that is a different story.. so your saying @mohamedfaiz it has to be in the field once regardless of the direction?

Comment: Sounds a LOT like full text search.

Comment: @mastarhian Absolutely correct, There is no direction. User search = "abraham my" it should display first row

Comment: @seanlange sorry once again, if user search "name name"= no records

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want full text search.  I would advise you to start with the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQmc_bkP_SAhUY6GMKHRScARYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Frelational-databases%2Fsearch%2Ffull-text-search&usg=AFQjCNGaypFsziizi8iFvkE0nyocRzydVA&sig2=Lt4LfPLuGkiGBsVm4AbucQ).

If you really want to use `like` and you want to pass in the words the way you are doing, then I would suggest splitting the string:

```
with terms as (
      select cast(left(@search, charindex(' ', @search + ' ') - 1) as varchar(max)) as term,
             cast(stuff(@search, 1, charindex(' ', @search + ' ') + 1, '') as varchar(max)) as rest
      union all
      select cast(left(rest, charindex(' ', rest + ' ') - 1) as varchar(max)),
             cast(stuff(rest, 1, charindex(' ', rest + ' ') + 1, '') as varchar(max))
      from terms
      where term <> ''
    )
select s.*
from sampleTable s cross apply
     (select count(*) as numterms,
             sum(case when t.term in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) then 1 else 0 end) as nummatches
      from terms t
     ) tt
where tt.numterms = tt.nummatches ;
```

Comment: he's one of the best if not the best.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The last line `t.nummatches` is showing error

Comment: @gordonlinoff I change to `ttnummatches` and then when I execute, this error shows `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "term" of recursive query "terms".`

Comment: @mohamedfaiz . . . I don't know why SQL Server is so picky about string data types in recursive CTEs.  Casting to a common length fixes this problem.